# Kotlin: How to map URL with Regex

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to map Slug URL with Regex URL mentioned below.

```
Regex URL - /openPage/*/*
Slug URL -/openPage/{category}/{subCategory}
URL - /openPage/ABC/XYZ
```

where after pattern matching, I should get like,
category = ABC
subCategory = XYZ

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into substrings of regex. You can match and extract substrings using `(` and `)`.

Comment: Hi @shkschneider, I didn't get. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a regex? They are great if you have a unique pattern match problem to solve, but if it's a standard thing (like URLs) there is almost certainly a library that can do it for you more easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into matching groups in Regex. They can be used to get specific parts of a regular expression after matching. For more info you can read [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). For your use-case you can use the following Regex:

```
\/openPage\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5iPAmrY-g8PaxWXP)

And here's how you can do that in Kotlin:

```
val regex = "\\/openPage\\/([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\/]+)".toRegex()
val match = regex.matchEntire("/openPage/ABC/XYZ")
val category = match?.groups?.get(1)?.value
val subCategory = match?.groups?.get(2)?.value
```

This way you will have your category and subCategory as `String?`.